# Coefficients of power series with binomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I am trying to get the coefficients of the power series of $\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$.

Rewriting gets us to  $(1 + \frac{2z}{1-z})^{0.5}$. Now using the binomial theorem gets us $\sum_{k=0}^n {\frac{1}{2}\choose k} (\frac{2z}{1-z})^k $ but didnt get far with that.

Comment: How about rewrite to $(-1+\frac{2}{1-z})^{0.5}$, expand it with binomial theorem and use $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ ?

Comment: @Miscellaneous Im getting $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {0.5\choose k}(-1)^{(0.5-k)}(\frac{2}{1-z})^k$. Following up that $(\frac{2}{1-z})^k = 2^k (\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n)^k$ and that ${0.5 \choose k} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$ i could simplified it a little bit but still didnt get far with that because i am still left with $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n)^k$

Answer (score 4):

You could write $$\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}=\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ and then expand $$(1+x)(1-x^2)^{-\frac12}$$ and get $$1+x+\frac12x^2+\frac12x^3+\frac38x^4+\frac38x^5+\frac{5}{16}x^6+\frac{5}{16}x^7+...$$

This is convenient since all the coefficients occur in identical pairs...

Comment: I see i was overthinking too much. I have tried this one already and my solution was right after all (after checking the coefficients per hand). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your comment on where you are blocked, consider that
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left( {\sum\limits_{0 \le n} {z^n } } \right)^k  = \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - z}}} \right)^k  = \left( {1 - z} \right)^{ - k}  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{0 \le j} {\left( { - 1} \right)^j \left( \begin{array}{c}
  - k \\ 
 j \\ 
 \end{array} \right)z^j }  = \sum\limits_{0 \le j} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 j + k - 1 \\ 
 j \\ 
 \end{array} \right)z^j }  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$